# Is $f(x)$ a function?

Tags: functions, notation

If we have, say $f(x)=x^2+1$, then is it correct to say that $f(x)$ is a function, or should one think that $f(x)$ is a value of the function $f$ at point $x$.

Comment: The function is denoted by $f$. The symbol $f(x)$ denotes the value of $f$ evaluated at the point $x$. However, lot of times $f(x)$ denotes the function: it depends on taste.

Comment: It depends on what $x$ is, if you treat it as a variable then $f(x)$ is a function. If you treat it as a constant then $f(x)$ is a constant. Let's say we have two variables $x,y$ then $f(x)+f(y)=x^2+y^2+2$ becomes a multi-variable function and it is not $2f$ nor $f$ evaluated at $x+y$.

Comment: $f$ is a function and $f(x)$ is a number (the number you get when you plug $x$ into $f$).  However, people are kind of sloppy about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)$ is often defined as being the **function of $x$**, or '$f$ of $x$'. It is the function evaluated at an $x$ value, it is summarised on Wikipedia's [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) page as:

> The output of a function $f$ corresponding to an input $x$ is denoted by $f(x)$

Using your example: $f(x) = x^2 +1$, say we wished to evaluate the function at $x = 3$, then it would be

$$f(3) = 3^2 +1 = 10$$